# RabbitMQ: round-robin for multiple consumer

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, round-robin

Project consist of three main things:

- Producer (device) send data to broker on MQTT protocol
- RabbitMQ broker
- Consumer (spring AMQP) for communication between application and broker.

***(device MQTT protocol) producer --> RabbitMQ <-- consumer (Spring app use AMQP protocol)***

I use MQTTX Client Toolbox for emulate producer:

```
quick.white.rabbit - topic
ewogICAibWF0cml4IjoiZm9sbG93IHRoZSB3aGl0ZSByYWJiaXTigKYiLAogICAiZGF0ZSI6Ik1hcmNoIDMxLCAxOTk5Igp9 - Base64 encoding data
```

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {
    @Bean
    public TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("amq.topic");
    }
    @Bean
    public Queue matrixQueue(){
        return new Queue("matrix.queue");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding(TopicExchange exchange,
                             Queue matrixQueue) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(matrixQueue)
                .to(exchange)
                .with("*.*.rabbit");
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class RabbitMQConsumer {

    static void dumb(Object payload, Map<String, Object> headers){
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        headers.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + "=" + v));
        System.out.println(payload);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "#{matrixQueue.name}")
    public void consumePayload(@Payload String encodedMessage, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers){
        String payload = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedMessage));
        dumb(payload, headers);
    }
}
```

I run two instance of same application consumer on different port 8081 and 8082

```
    java -jar target/consumer_rabbitmq-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=8081
    java -jar target/consumer_rabbitmq-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=8082
```

The **problem** is the message arrives to two consumer  at the same time

```
java -jar target/deep_dive_rabbitmq-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=8081
-----------------------------------
amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT
amqp_receivedRoutingKey=quick.white.rabbit
amqp_receivedExchange=amq.topic
x-mqtt-publish-qos=0
x-mqtt-dup=false
amqp_deliveryTag=3
amqp_consumerQueue=spring.gen-X6e3uiz5S-K4_RA0tt89cg
amqp_redelivered=false
id=debc649f-9ae1-82a8-be5f-0a3f2c9e2f87
amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-brMleQwCDNmcCHyT_lbF8A
amqp_lastInBatch=false
timestamp=1708633236541
{
   "matrix":"follow the white rabbit…",
   "date":"March 31, 1999"
}
```

```
java -jar target/deep_dive_rabbitmq-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=8082
-----------------------------------
amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT
amqp_receivedRoutingKey=quick.white.rabbit
amqp_receivedExchange=amq.topic
x-mqtt-publish-qos=0
x-mqtt-dup=false
amqp_deliveryTag=3
amqp_consumerQueue=spring.gen-Ym1vcVbUQ4aZqnG3Bu4OyA
amqp_redelivered=false
id=dd1a5d91-4972-dcca-0669-dc40f9d85a15
amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-zqy6gfLSLaZSf3H3W00M1A
amqp_lastInBatch=false
timestamp=1708633236541
{
   "matrix":"follow the white rabbit…",
   "date":"March 31, 1999"
}
```

How can i configure RabbitMQ to use round robin consumer, each time a message is delivered, the next consumer in the queue will receive the next message ? Currently it goes for  two both consumer simultaniously.

```
MESSAGE 1 // port 8081

MESSAGE 2 // port 8082

MESSAGE 3 // port 8081

MESSAGE 4 // port 8082
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that goal you must use the same queue for all consumers. The `AnonymousQueue` makes all of the to be subscribed with their own queue, so all of them receives the same message.

See more info in this tutorial: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-spring-amqp

**UPDATE**

I thought about this though:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {
    @Bean
    public TopicExchange exchange(){
        return new TopicExchange("amq.topic");
    }
    @Bean
    public Queue matrixQueue(){
        return new Queue("matrix.queue");
    }
    @Bean
    public Binding binding(TopicExchange exchange, Queue matrixQueue) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(matrixQueue)
                .to(exchange)
                .with("*.*.rabbit");
    }
}
```

Since you didn't get it that `DirectExchange` matches only exactly to the routing key.

Comment: I changed the TopicExchange to DirectExchange and it screwed up something i can't receive data from broker anymore when i send it to 'quick.white.rabbit'
as i described above. I read the documents which you send and i understood that to achieve consumer round robin i should set prefetchCount propertie. Can you tell me is it possible to set 'prefetchCount' from yaml file? Do you have an working example of my case?

Comment: It must not be an `AnonymousQueue`. All your consumers must be subscribed to the same queue. Only this way RabbitMQ is able to distribute messages evenly. The property you are looking for is there: `spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.prefetch=1` My IDE gave me a hint. I'm not sure that I can write better sample than the mentioned tutorial.

Comment: I updated RabbitMQConfig class according to your advice but it wont works. All my consumer listen the same queue @RabbitListener(queues = "#{autoDeleteQueue.name}").  MQTTX Client Toolbox to quick.white.rabbit

Comment: Yeah... Sorry, I see. The MQTT publishes to some topic. The direct exchange follows exact matching of the routing key. Let's see if coming back to the `TopicExchange` would do the trick! The queue name might really not match to the original routing. The only point that one queue must be used for all the subscribers: https://medium.com/trendyol-tech/rabbitmq-exchange-types-d7e1f51ec825

Comment: Updated scripts above but nothing . Consumer doesn't receive message from broker.

Comment: Se an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: I noticed  interesting thing. If i change TopicExchange("amq.topic") to TopicExchange("my.topic.exchange") name it stop working and also the prop spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.prefetch=1 is not important for that case. I don't understand how name influence to this behavior

Comment: I see. The `amq.topic` is a default `TopicExchange` on the RabbitMQ broker and I guess  the MQTT protocol sends its messages exactly to this exchange. So, you definitely can live with that `TopicExchange("amq.topic")`. The `prefetch=1` is still has to be there to achieve a good round-robin between consumers on the same queue.